# how to center align a light box and hide a scrollbar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I m web designer and getting problem in adjustment of light box. light box is not center aligned at any resolution. it should be center aligned at any resolution. and i used a black overlay for transparency in background but it shows scrollbars in light box so its not look good .... plz tell how could i center align a lightbox and hide a scrollbar ..........

Thanks Mayur

Answer (score 0):

To centerize your list do this

```
body {padding: 0px; margin: opx;overflow: hidden;}
#wrapper{width: 50%; height: auto; margin: 0 auto; vetical-align: middle; text-align: -moz-center; !text-align: center;}
.List{color: #fff;}

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
     <asp:List CssClass="List" />
</div>
<body>
```